Telnyx Voice - Record Voicemail at caller end, if i did not Answered call
I need to ask caller to record voicemail if i did not answered call.
i am using Telnyx API webhook to ask caller to record, but its not working
use Telnyx\Telnyx;
Telnyx::setApiKey('{api key}');
// Handle incoming webhook
$rawData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($rawData, true);
switch ($data['data']['event_type']) {
        case 'call.hangup':
            // Check if the call was not answered
            if ($data['data']['payload']['hangup_cause'] == 'NO_ANSWER') {
                $callControlId = $data['data']['payload']['call_control_id'];
                playGreetingAndRecordVoicemail($callControlId);
            }
            break;
        case 'call.recording.saved':
            handleRecordingCompleted($data);
            break;
        default:
            break;
}

i am getting error "This call is no longer active and can't receive commands.", because after hangup event caller can not record voicemail,
i am not sure how to do this, how can i ask caller to record voicemail.

Probably worth contacting support
